# Java swing - Repaint is duplicating components (JButtons and JLabels) when re-sized

Tags: java, swing, resize, duplicates, jbutton

I am having this weird problem. My professor can't seem to duplicate it and the help he offers is minimal at best. So to the point. This code produces a JButton on a panel and adds to the Content Pane of the JFrame:

```
public myPanel extends JPanel {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    public myPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 40));
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicsDrawer) {
        super.paintComponent(graphicsDrawer);
        this.add(new JButton("A Button"));
    }
}
```

Here is the GUI code

```
public class myGUI {
    public myGUI() {
    }
    public void showGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Issues!!!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new myPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The GUI is then run by this class

```
// It is unnecessary to show here but I made a class that
// implements runnable that creates a myGUI object and calls
// showGUI
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RunnableGUI runGUI = new RunnableGUI();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runGUI);
}
```

This is my code at **bare** minimum. However I have isolated this and the issue still persists even with the bare essentials. Below is a photo I am having the issue with.

[Initial Frame w/ 1 button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feiYi.png)

[Vertical Re-size creates extra buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaaiE.png)

I have tried literally everything I could find and think of.

I think the frame repaints the button each time it is re-sized. However the frame must be able to be re-sized because of the assignment requirements.

Running Windows 8 w/ JRE 7, 8 (I will download 6 but I do not think that will help)

Comment: As a convention, class names are supposed to start with upper case letters to differentiate them from instances.

Comment: add your button in your constructor please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public myPanel extends JPanel {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    public myPanel() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 40));
        this.add(new JButton("A Button"));
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicsDrawer) {
        super.paintComponent(graphicsDrawer);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**NEVER** do this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicsDrawer) {
    super.paintComponent(graphicsDrawer);
    this.add(new JButton("A Button"));  // ***** yikes! ****
}
```

The paintComponent method is for painting **only**. You don't have full control over whether or even if it will be called, and it can be called **multiple** times, meaning lots of buttons being added. Also, you want to avoid component creational code or **any** code that slows down program flow within a painting method since these methods partly determine the perceived responsiveness of your GUI, and so you will want the painting methods (`paint` and `paintComponent`) to be lean, mean and ***fast***.

Add your button in your constructor or an initialization method so that you control how often that code gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have posted my original code. I will keep this in mind in the future. I did not do the this.add(new JButton("A Button")); I created one then added it but I see where I went stray. Thanks!